# XML to Python dataframe with nested tag structure

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I have a massive XML in the structure as show in the picture below. I need to parse this into a dataframe. My Dataframe would contain columns such as `FinInstrmGnlAttrbts_ID`, `FinInstrmGnlAttrbts_FullName`, etc.
I have no idea how to traverse XML tag structures in Python.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
_xt = et.parse("DLTINS_20171019_01of01.xml")
_xr = _xt.getroot()
_xr
for child in _xr:
    print (child.tag, child.attrib)
```

it gives me

```
{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01}Hdr {}
{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01}Pyld {}
```

[image: XML Structure I want to pass]

Comment: Oh no!  What if a girl had just the right answer for you?

Comment: @MrFelixU Then I would say Merci Mademoiselle grandement apprécier to her. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: You can try [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) or something else to "flatten" your XML. Search for "flatten XML Python" to find more.

Comment: You do get some output. What is the problem with it?